# How to calculate the sorted position of a value in a range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice

I we have a computed value (i.e. a formula) for each row (column *value*)

| name | value | position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1.2 |  |
| b | 0.9 |  |
| c | 1.3 |  |
| d | 1.1 |  |

how do I find out the sorted position for each row?, this is:

| name | value | position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1.2 | *3* |
| b | 0.9 | *1* |
| c | 1.3 | *4* |
| d | 1.1 | *2* |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the `RANK` function is here for.

You need (in `C2` and filled down) something like:

```
=RANK(B2,B:B,1)
```

This ranks the value in `B2` compared to all values in the `B:B` range, and sorted in ascending order (smallest first.)

Comment: Thanks !!!!!!!!!